# find a string in sentence in R

Tags: r, string, for-loop, if-statement

Hi i am trying to find a short text in a sentence and then do some manipulation.It easy in java but in R i am having some issue.I am not reaching if condition. 
Here is my code

```
rm(list=ls())
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

shortText= c('grt','gr8','bcz','ur')


tweet=c('stats is gr8','this car is good','your movie is grt','i hate your book of hatred','food is awsome'
        )
tweet=data.frame(tweet, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(row in 1:nrow(tweet)) {

tweetWords=strsplit(tweet[row,]," ")
print(tweetWords)
  for (word in 1:length(tweetWords)) {
    if(tweetWords[word] %in% shortText){
      print('we have a match')
    }

  }
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Maybe there is better way to do this.

Comment: when i find short text ie. gr8 or other word in my sentence , it should print 'we have a match'

Comment: you are missing a closing brace. Are you sure you posted the right code?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495024/extracting-a-word-from-a-sentence-in-r

Comment: Something like this `ifelse(grepl(paste0(shortText, collapse ="\\b|\\b "), tweet$tweet), "We have a match", "We don't have a match")`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward base R option using `grepl`:

```
shortText <- c('grt','gr8','bcz','ur')
tweet <- c('stats is gr8','this car is good','your movie is grt','i hate your book of hatred','food is awsome')

res <- sapply(shortText, function(x) grepl(paste0("\\b", x, "\\b"), tweet))
tweet[rowSums(res)]

[1] "stats is gr8" "stats is gr8"
```

### Demo

The basic idea is to generate a matrix whose rows are the tweets and whose columns are the keywords.  Should we find one or more 1 (true) values across a given row, it means that tweet fired on one or more keywords.

Note carefully that I surround each search term by word boundaries `\b`.  This is necessary that a search term does not falsely match as a substring of a larger word.

Comment: tweet[rowSums(res)==1]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to improve this. But a quick solution with minimal changes to your code:

```
shortText= c('grt','gr8','bcz','ur')


tweet=c('stats is gr8','this car is good','your movie is grt','i hate your book of hatred','food is awsome'
)
tweet=data.frame(tweet, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(row in 1:nrow(tweet)) {

  tweetWords=strsplit(tweet[row,]," ")
  print(tweetWords)
  for (word in 1:length(tweetWords)) {
    if(any(tweetWords[word][[1]] %in% shortText)){
      print('we have a match')
    }

  }
}
```

returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "stats" "is"    "gr8"  

[1] "we have a match"
[[1]]
[1] "this" "car"  "is"   "good"

[[1]]
[1] "your"  "movie" "is"    "grt"  

[1] "we have a match"
[[1]]
[1] "i"      "hate"   "your"   "book"   "of"     "hatred"

[[1]]
[1] "food"   "is"     "awsome"
```

Adding `any` will execute the `if` statement if any of the boolean operators are T, without it it would have used the first element only

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something like that:

```
cbind(tweet, ifelse(sapply(shortText, grepl, x = tweet), "Match is found", "No match"))

             tweet                        grt              gr8              bcz       
    [1,] "stats is gr8"               "No match"       "Match is found" "No match"
    [2,] "this car is good"           "No match"       "No match"       "No match"
    [3,] "your movie is grt"          "Match is found" "No match"       "No match"
    [4,] "i hate your book of hatred" "No match"       "No match"       "No match"
    [5,] "food is awsome"             "No match"       "No match"       "No match"
     ur              
    [1,] "No match"      
    [2,] "No match"      
    [3,] "Match is found"
    [4,] "Match is found"
    [5,] "No match"
```